# Pop shell changes tab alignment in Firefox

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell-extension, system76

I have recently installed Pop Shell and I have noticed that in Firefox the first tab is shifted to the right, as can be seen in the following picture:

[image]

Any ideas of what is causing this behavior and how to fix it? I have played with gaps and the other settings of the Pop Shell menu but nothing. Only when the window is maximized the tabs are shown correctly.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the Pop Shell was installed by following these [instructions](https://support.system76.com/articles/pop-shell/).

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.